# Competitive programming problem I am stuck in

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

So there is a list of points (x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),...(xn,yn,zn).

You can perform an operation O on any number of these points.

Operation O results in (x,y,z)= (max(x1,x2,...xn),max(y1,y2,...yn),max(z1,z2,...zn)).

Given (x,y,z), you need to determine whether it is possible to perform operation O on some of the points in the list  to get (x,y,z) as a result.

For eg: You are given points(1,2,1),(3,1,4),(5,2,1).
Can you perform O operation to get 1) (3,2,1) 2) (1,1,1)

First line contains n and q i.e the number of points and no. of queries

Next n lines contain the n points space seperated

Next q lines contain the q points which are the queries

```
1<=q<=10^5
1<=n<=10^5
```

x,y,z are integers

Input:

```
2 2
1 3 5
5 3 1
5 3 5
3 3 3
```

Expected Output:

```
YES
NO
```

My logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    cin>>x>>y>>z;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {

        if(arr[j][0]==x && arr[j][1]<=y && arr[j][2]<=z)
            first=1;
        if(arr[j][0]<=x && arr[j][1]==y && arr[j][2]<=z)
            second=1;
        if(arr[j][0]<=x && arr[j][1]<=y && arr[j][2]==z)
            third=1;
        if(first+second+third==3)
            break;
    }
    if(first+second+third==3)
        cout<<"YES\n";
    else
    {
        cout<<"NO\n";
    }
    first=0;
    second=0;
    third=0;
}
```

Note: Here arr[][] contains the given coordinates.
for every x y z in queries q I am performing this operation.

Few test cases are failing giving me a runtime error (Time limit Exceeded). Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant language tags.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the site, I have removed 2 language tags

Comment: please provide a [mre] with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: I have added the inputs and expected Outputs. Hope it will be clear now

Comment: @roccok123 Can you also tell what are the limits (ranges) for `q`, `n`, and coordinates `x`, `y`, `z`? Also are they all integers?

Comment: @roccok123 Also what is the time limit to solve the problem for given limits?

Comment: @Arty Thanks for asking. I have added it. Yes, all are integers

Comment: @Arty , The time limit is 2 seconds

Comment: "runtime error" Does that mean an error occurring at runtime? Or is it an error because the time your programs runs is to long (often "Time Limit Exceeded")?

Comment: @Yunnosch Time limit exceeded

Comment: @roccok123 If not a secret, can you please also share a link to original task at online contest site where you got the problem from?

Comment: @roccok123 So what's the news? Can you possibly provide the link to original online contest site/problem where you got this task from?

Comment: @roccok123 I create [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64539635/941531) with very fast solution. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct but slow, has `O(q * n)` complexity which is `10^10` at maximum, too much.

I've solved your task using sorting plus merging search, which has `O(n log n + q log q)` complexity.

The algorithm is as follows:

For each of three cases, `(x, y, z)`, `(y, x, z)`, `(z, x, y)`, signified as coordinates `(i0, i1, i2)`, we do next:

1. Sort all points and queries by tuple `(i0, i1, i2)`.
2. Among each equal coordinates `i0` compute cumulative minimum of `i2`.
3. Merge sorted points and queries next way: For each range of queries and points with equal `i0` and `i1` take rightmost minimal `i2`. If such minimal `i2` for point is greater than query's `i2` then answer for this query is `NO`, otherwise is probably `YES` (probably meaning that it should be `YES` for all 3 orderings of `(x, y, z)`/`(y, x, z)`/`(z, x, y)`).

Basically algorithm above does same thing as your algorithm does, it finds point with equal `x`, `y`, or `z` so that other two coordinates are not greater. But does it through fast algorithm of merging two sorted arrays. So that merging itself takes just `O(q + n)` time, while whole algorithm time is dominated by sorting algorithms taking `O(q log q + n log n)` time.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZRb5w4EH7nV0xTaWUUEi1EkaIsyz2c7uFerpVaVapWqCKss7HCYoPNXtNmf3s6NgZskkserjwY8/mb8cx4PEMpxFlZFfXu6ek9q8uq21JIGZeqpcU@CybsQEvFWxcpqh1vmbrzaKoTFXWBUqotq1UWBJ1k9Q7qYk@lKEoKuLAKAvUg6JbeQoekq28KuqvViCEEf3Lebj9PmNkg7dEI/HfWv6VD781OLT4QvtDys96b7kVVKLRSsh8UN2fLCIZpPE2TLJCqUKyEA2db@MSrAyWTJih5LRUsQMgIXoAbhK0d3VWGwAOVIfwMAJ@iUxw@tlTAGjaLnJjvBaCEmQ0qeNjT9SPPy4oWLQlXDtRSSVu0ip9ro0noLN7yFsjgCm6zXOErhYG5gtNTFo7sXp3o5N23m6K8J/viHgV10MmOqnSZEb5heRiB/oq9r2T8Yu7@@pks5a0i8vyG7lhNkCnPab3Vk431ffC4mkWgDeEsgxvOK/jpqW6p6traGMDQuipE34YPFHp8BOKsrdfu4mIBxFOmH7Meu5piX1PsaYqtpmd6Rl2JqyvRdD/cbrCOdn7sXzZtXs36IU8zyEDqFJSN7KV1XhEDCRm6kM7IZoDcK4I3ZM9qmWgpP5P6ZShxOTFJFLySW5N0n13OkbFbIEwHb6kDOpwFCmwYnEGch/Bu7cP5LFyDCUM4LWmK4UDAAnN9jXNigGgu4EgYnxFDIcO1Z/DcxUb7iPktrK@NdrbxnG1cb@11LvHGowSOG23ERaaPYMOaPMxXXmTeaebMXV4rVnd0Iv57xyqKURRepHUy2xtqHBT5kHPLaTtfNVor/P1RZ7Z2ldozcpXa83G1zq6kdfe2qCRdveHM8QW3TiF@3TXNyMcr6FgyMOMZM12P8P@MROxEIpsr1SSbSyK3y8nvjNMxOAaBbov7QtdPq89mZ90nZzNdz5LVkGVghmY1NZy/a9Ep3XFyt40t4DD2vLJWrrWHscEchnicGs6bbQZJz2qAU0@@R/AQwY@Z973Z3/XwoIfZ@uHl/mR1eeXULaaOq8IUwB42wSAaqUMXMUXSr5G6feOZkfHGR6DajlqS@S9I8QTw1wFPvd8jMt3eJeDq8lVCYgjxS4T/CLJfgabULjkec5oC0ZUHy9sfcPL1r08ncA0n/3w4CfUStt@q120bKabOMXh6SiAJYriAy@ASx9iMl8EFjhe/AA)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

typedef int CoordT;
typedef tuple<CoordT, CoordT, CoordT> CoordsT;
typedef vector<CoordsT> CoordsVecT;

template <size_t i0, size_t i1, size_t i2>
static void Solve(CoordsVecT const & ps, CoordsVecT const & qs, vector<bool> & yes) {
    auto Prep = [&](auto & s, auto const & o){
        s.clear();
        s.reserve(o.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < o.size(); ++i)
            s.push_back(make_tuple(get<0>(o[i]), get<1>(o[i]), get<2>(o[i]), i));
            
        sort(s.begin(), s.end(), [](auto const & l, auto const & r) -> bool {
            return get<i0>(l) < get<i0>(r) || get<i0>(l) == get<i0>(r) && (
                get<i1>(l) < get<i1>(r) || get<i1>(l) == get<i1>(r) &&
                    get<i2>(l) < get<i2>(r)
            );
        });
    };
    vector< tuple<CoordT, CoordT, CoordT, size_t> > sps, sqs;
    Prep(sps, ps);
    Prep(sqs, qs);
    vector<CoordT> mins2(sps.size());
    CoordT cmin2 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sps.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || get<i0>(sps[i - 1]) != get<i0>(sps[i]))
            cmin2 = get<i2>(sps[i]);
        cmin2 = std::min(cmin2, get<i2>(sps[i]));
        mins2[i] = cmin2;
    }
    for (size_t iq = 0, ip = 0; iq < sqs.size(); ++iq) {
        auto & cyes = yes[get<3>(sqs[iq])];
        if (!cyes)
            continue;
        while (ip < sps.size() && get<0>(sps[ip]) < get<0>(sqs[iq]))
            ++ip;
        if (ip >= sps.size() || get<0>(sps[ip]) != get<0>(sqs[iq])) {
            cyes = false;
            continue;
        }
        while (ip + 1 < sps.size() && get<0>(sps[ip + 1]) == get<0>(sqs[iq]) && get<1>(sps[ip + 1]) <= get<1>(sqs[iq]))
            ++ip;
        if (ip >= sps.size() || get<1>(sps[ip]) > get<1>(sqs[iq]) || mins2[ip] > get<2>(sqs[iq])) {
            cyes = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t n = 0, q = 0;
    cin >> n >> q;
    auto Input = [](CoordsVecT & v, size_t cnt) {
        v.reserve(v.size() + cnt);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
            CoordT x, y, z;
            cin >> x >> y >> z;
            v.push_back(make_tuple(x, y, z));
        }
    };
    CoordsVecT ps, qs;
    Input(ps, n);
    Input(qs, q);
    vector<bool> yes(qs.size(), true);
    Solve<0, 1, 2>(ps, qs, yes);
    Solve<1, 0, 2>(ps, qs, yes);
    Solve<2, 0, 1>(ps, qs, yes);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < qs.size(); ++i)
        cout << (yes[i] ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2 2
1 3 5
5 3 1
5 3 5
3 3 3
```

Output:

```
YES
NO
```